# Checking if a text file is at the end

Tags: c#, loading

I currently have a separate class that handles the loading in of a file which is this method:

```
public string loadFile(string filename)
{
    FileStream fs;
    StreamReader sr;
    fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();       
    }      
    fs.Close();
    return content;
}
```

I also want to check if it has reached at the end. This method needs a return value but where the return is at the moment does not work.

I am calling this method in a different class as:

```
fileHandler.loadFile("text.txt");
```

Is there  a simple fix to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring your `content` variable in an inner scope and trying to use it from outside it.

Try declaring your `content` variable outside the `while` block

```
    string content = string.Empty; 
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
      content = sr.ReadToEnd();       
    }      
    fs.Close();
    return content;
```

Note that you also need to give it a value, so that if your code doesn't enter the `while` block, it'll return something. I've given it `string.Empty`, but you could give it `null` or whatever.

**Update**: As a further tip, `ReadToEnd` will always read up to the end, so you don't need to check for `EndOfStream` at all (it *will* be at the end of the stream if this function exits cleanly, always).

And, as a practice code, that's fine, but this whole function is already implemented in the framework as `File.ReadAllText`, so this code would be equivalent:

```
public string loadFile(string filename)
{
  return File.ReadAllText(filename);
}
```

And once you have that, there's no point on having your `loadFile` method at all (it's just a method that calls another method with the very same parameters, so it's just a redundant function call), just use `File.ReadAllText()` when you were planning to use this method.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm sure it was this simple! I did try declaring it before the while loop but I did not include the string.Empty, so I was wrecking my brain trying to fix it!

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Just as a bonus tip, `ReadToEnd` will always read up to the end, so you don't really need that `while` block at all, or the check :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class member 
    bool _reachedEnd = false

```
public string loadFile(string filename)
{
    FileStream fs;
    StreamReader sr;
    fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    _reachedEnd= false;
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();       
    }
    _reachedEnd= true;      
    fs.Close();
    return content;
}
```

also the requested function:

```
public bool reachedEnd()
{
    return _reachedEnd;
}
```

just be carful when you call reachedEnd() since it returns a value which is set to false by default.

Comment: There's no point on this... after calling this method, `_reachedEnd` will be always `true`, no matter what (unless there are exceptions, but those should be managed differently)

Comment: after you load a file which has already been read, you expect to get    true
when you load a new file it is updated.

Comment: `true` is updated to `true`, so it makes no sense, at least for single-threaded code (and it's just wrong for multithreading). The only way this would be practical, would be to determine the question, *"has any file has ever been read using this function?"*, in which case, calling it `_reachedEnd` makes no semantic sense, either as a private variable or (worse) as a class member.

Comment: true is updated to false before the while statement, I do agree it is not an elegant solution to say the least.

Comment: In a single thread, there's no use of that point in time where its false, so unless you actually give some use to that variable before it gets then updated to true afterwards, it's just a pointless asignment. And if thinking of a multithreaded or async scenario, there are plenty of other safety measures you'd need to have before that

Comment: That's not what OP asked for? i thought he wanted a function which returns just that. my mistake :O

Comment: I'd say the meaning of the OPs question got lost in translation, since that variable made no sense in an scenario like this

Comment: I totally agree. I just thought of a solution for OP's question - a function which returns the current state of the reading process. I guess I'm the one to blame on that mess